# how to calculate size of array which is passed to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

Have a look at following code

```
void fun( int *p )
{
    // is there any solution to calculate size of array as we are not explicitly passing its size.
}

void main ()
{
    int a[5];
    fun (a);
}
```

Is there any solution to calculate size of array in function or explicitly passing its size is the only solution?

Comment: Explicitly passing the size is the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot.**

It's just one pointer, which contains no size info of the array. That's why it's a common implementation to pass the size of the array as a second parameter to the function.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer `p` contains no data about the size of the array. You don't quite *have* to pass the size as a parameter - you could end the array with a `0` like strings do, or hardcode the length, or do any of a number of other things - but without some sort of additional machinery, you can't get the length from just a pointer.

Comment: Good idea to use a sentinel, +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass an array to a function, the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. Thus what you are actually passing is a pointer to the first element of the array, not the array itself. In fact, you can't pass to or return an array from a function. They are not first class objects in `C`. Hence, you must pass the length of the array to the function as well.

```
void fun(int *p, int len) {
    // function body
}

int main(void) {
    int a[5];
    fun(a, 5);
}
```